# How can I remove a child from another child in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to access a `div` in a `li` element, and then delete it. But I need to access it through another parenting `div`, which contains the `li`. My attempts at this have not worked. Here is what I have tried: `parentDiv.childNodes[0].removeChild(document.getElementsById('removeThisChild')`.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

 
Thanks :)

**Update**

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
   var ul = document.getElementById('ul')
   ul.childNodes[0].removeChild(document.getElementById('div'))
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="ul">
 <li id="li">this is the LI text <div id='div'>this is the div text</div></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your html tags too, like html page. There a lot of options.

Comment: Can you give the `div`, that you want to remove, an `id`?

Comment: I don't know if your code will work - but in the interest of correcting a typo - you do not include the "s" on Element when selecting elements using getElementById:...parentDiv.childNodes[0].removeChild(document.getElementById('removeThisChild')....

Comment: I've added the HTML doc to the OP

Comment: 'document.getElementById('div').remove()' and thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a code pen - http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/dMVgzb

```
var child = document.querySelector('#li');
child.parentElement.querySelector('li > div').remove();
```